# Python - Comparing the values of keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Say the we have the following two dictionaries in `Python`:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': 4}

dict2 = {'c':2, 'd':1, 'b':2, 'a':1}
```

Now, I'm assuming that the values in `dict1` are the correct values. How can I compare `dict2` to `dict1`, such that if the value of the key in `dict2` is similar to that in `dict1` the program returns `True`, and if it is different, it returns `False`?

Thanks.

Comment: Define 'similar'.

Comment: `dict1 == dict2`?

Comment: What should the output be if `dict1` has keys that are not in `dict2`? How about if `dict2` has keys that are not in `dict1`?

Comment: Are you trying to compare all keys at once?  If not, how do you determine which key(s) to check?

Answer (score 0):

If by similar you mean equal, then you can just directly compare them:

```
def compare_dictionaries(correct_dictionary,dictionary_to_check):
    for key,correct_value in correct_dictionary.items():
        if dictionary_to_check[key] != correct_value:
            return False
    return True
```

The above will throw a `KeyError` exception if you are missing a key in the dictionary you need to check and does nothing to handle if the dictionary you are checking contains extra keys.

Comment: You can easily get `KeyError` exception.

Comment: @vishes_shell I agree.

Comment: This can be condensed to `all(key in dict2 and dict2[key] == val for (key, val) in dict1.items())` if this is the desired behavior.

Comment: @vishes_shell  Assuming some behavior I made an edit.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Thats true, but is less explicit and is not as clear for understanding of the logic requested.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper - that can be further condensed to `dict1 == dict2`

Comment: I suggest you remove double `if` and keep EAFP coding style.

Comment: @vishes_shell thanks for tips, I made adjustments.

Comment: @zwer - no, my expression allows `dict2` to have keys that are not in `dict1`, while dict equality does not. I disagree that `all` is less clear than a `for` loop but it's hardly with arguing over.

Answer (score 0):

## First implementation

```
# Both dictionaries can have different keys

dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': 4} # correct dict 
dict2 = {'c':2, 'd':1, 'b':2, 'a':1} # test dict
if all(map(lambda x: dict2.get(x, "dict2") == dict1.get(x, "dict1"), dict2)):
    print "same"
else:
    print "different"
```

Test case #1 gives "same"

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': 4, 'e':5} # correct dict
dict2 = {'c':3, 'd':4, 'b':2, 'a':1} # test dict
```

Test case #2 gives "different"

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': 4 } # correct dict
dict2 = {'c':3, 'd':4, 'b':2, 'a':1, 'e':5} # test dict
```

## Second implementation (different from first, see test results)

```
# Both dictionaries can have different keys

dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': 4} # correct dict 
dict2 = {'c':2, 'd':1, 'b':2, 'a':1} # test dict
if set(dict1.keys()) == set(dict2.keys())  and set(dict1.values()) == set(dict2.values()):
    print "same"
else:
    print "different"
```

Test case #1 gives "different"

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': 4, 'e':5} # correct dict
dict2 = {'c':3, 'd':4, 'b':2, 'a':1} # test dict
```

Test case #2 gives "different"

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': 4 } # correct dict
dict2 = {'c':3, 'd':4, 'b':2, 'a':1, 'e':5} # test dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that dict1 key: values are what everything is being compared to.

```
dict2 = {'c':2, 'd':1, 'b':2, 'a':1}

def compareDict(d2):
  dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': 4}

  for key in d2:
    if d2[key] == dict1[key]:
      print("{} key has similar value of {}; It is True".format(key, 
      d2[key]))
    else:
      print("{} key does not have similar value as dict1 key, it has a 
      value of {}; It is False".format(key, d2[key]))

compareDict(dict2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the keys are same using `xor` operation and then check the value with corresponding `key` of the `dictionary`. Hope this will help.

```
dict1 = {'a':2, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': 4}
dict2 = {'c':2, 'd':1, 'b':2, 'a':1}
# XOR operator for for checking all key are same.
check_keys= set(dict1.keys()) ^ set(dict2.keys())
keys = set(dict2.keys())
check = False
# a=0 if all key are same.
a = len(check_keys)
# if all key are same than check the value with corresponding key
if not a:
    check = True
    for key in keys:
        if dict1[key] == dict2[key]:
            pass
        else:
            check = False
            break
print(check)
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare dictionaries by size, keys and value for each key by giving a boolean flag.

```
def compareDictionaries(source, target, compareValues):
    ## compare if they are same
    if (source == target):
        return True
    ## covers scenario where target has more keys than source
    if (len(target) > len(source)):
        print("target has more keys than source")
        return False
    ## iterate over target keys to check if they exists in
    ## source and depending on compareValues flag compare key's
    ## values
    for key, values in target.items():
        if (key in source.keys()):
            if (compareValues):
                if(not (source[key] == target[key])):
                    print ("key(" + key + ") don't have same values!")
                    return False
        else:
            print ("key(" + key + ") not found in source!")
            return False
    return True

dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd': 4}
dict2 = {'c':5, 'd':4, 'b':2, 'a':1}
if (compareDictionaries(dict1, dict2, False)):
    print("Pass")
else:
    print("Fail")
```